# How can I "upgrade" the jQuery version within the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

While on-site with a client, I was proposing an upgrade of the jQuery version the client is using (ie, from jQuery 1.5 to 1.11). The client has minor concern that their version of [TimeGlider](http://timeglider.com/) won't be compatible with the newer jQuery. I'm not familiar with TimeGlider, so they browsed (wth Chrome) to a page with TimeGlider to demonstrate it to me.

I thought I'd be slick and "upgrade" the DOM's jQuery library, using developer tools, to settle the question immediately. I know [one way to import the jQuery 1.11 library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15954721/1430996), but this technique would necessitate a simple way to first remove the old jQuery version. Perhaps there's a better approach.

Of course this is trivial to edit within the sourcecode, but I really wanted to do it within the DOM, via developer tools.

How can I "upgrade" the jQuery version within the DOM?

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need to remove the old version, because the new script tag you add will overwrite the jQuery variable with the newer version. You actually have to use the noConflict option if you want to be able to use multiple jQuery versions on the same page, so your script tag solution should just work.

Comment: If the plugin is well written then it already has a reference to the "old" jquery passed in as a parameter (replacing the global jquery will have no effect).  Not to mention the fact that whatever initialization it has done was already done with the old version as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Go to the `Sources` tab.
- Find jQuery file (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>).
- [Add a breakpoint](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#add-remove-breakpoints) in the first (non-comment) line of the script.
- Reload page.
- When execution stops, select whole contents of the file and replace them with contents of [jquery-1.11.0.min.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js).
- Save the changes (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>).
- File will recompile and website will run jQuery 1.11.0.

[image: recompiled version of jQuery]

Comment: Great solution. I sense you've had a similar need to do this before?

Comment: @JeromyFrench TBH I figured it just now :) The other solution that comes to my mind is to create an extension that returns jQuery 1.11 whenever this specific jquery.js file is requested by the browser ([good place to start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-BlockingResponse)). Or use any proxy app, such as [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Comment: Well, you've taught me a new, powerful, developer tools feature. Thank you.

Comment: @JeromyFrench Happy to hear that. Enjoy!